# Unit Test in Swift

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I'm studying unit test in swift and I would like to know if I'm doing the right way.

Here I have the model

```
struct ChangePasswordRequest: Encodable {
    var email: String
    var newPassword: String
    var token: String
}
```

And here the unit test

```
import XCTest
@testable import MyProject

class ChangePasswordRequestTests: XCTestCase {

    var changePasswordRequest: ChangePasswordRequest!

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        changePasswordRequest = nil
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testChangePasswordRequest() {

        // given
        let email = "abc@def.com.br"
        let newPassword = "abc123"
        let token =
        """
        rF1rHbYVCpcfyo6K2e7Q68QvKYdeOMt0vDXYehggGU3kx8XiuGmQylXabxbGAyUmSK9RnbL
        """

        // when
        changePasswordRequest = ChangePasswordRequest(email: email, newPassword: newPassword, token: token)

        let requestJSON = """
        {"email":"\(email)","token":"\(token)","newPassword":"\(newPassword)"}
        """

        changePasswordRequest = ChangePasswordRequest(email: email, newPassword: newPassword, token: token)
        guard let encodedRequest = try? JSONEncoder().encode(changePasswordRequest) else {
            XCTFail()
            return
        }

        // then
        XCTAssertEqual(String(data: encodedRequest, encoding: .utf8)!, requestJSON, "Any JSON key differs from model.")

    }

}
```

I never worked with unit test. It's possible to improve this test?

Comment: This might be better suited for Code Review:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/